# Problem with React Drag and Drop (Reactdnd)

Tags: reactjs, chess, react-dnd

I'm using react's dragndrop (react-dnd) module in my chess program to drag and drop the pieces. I am using a chessboard import for react called chessboardjsx, which utilizes reactdnd. My code is just importing and running chessboardjsx. I get an error when I run the application, which is shown in the image below.
[image: the error]
It says there's a legacy context API, and tells me to update the components DragDropContext, DragLayer, DragSource, and DropTarget. I had to do some digging (since I'm new to React) but I found all of these components in the react-dnd module, as shown in the image below.
[image: react-dnd]

The effect of this is that when I drop a piece in my app, it just returns to the starting point. If anybody knows how I can fix this problem, I would really appreciate your ideas. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing `<REACT.StrictMode>` wrapper?  I had issues before with the Drag and Drop and commenting that out fixed it.